# "Email" not visible in Activity Timeline View

Tags: lightning

In my System Administrator profile, I am able to see the "**Email**" button in the *Activity Timeline view* as shown below

[image]

This highlighted "**Email**" button is not visible for another user with a different profile.

The page layout is the same for both the profiles (checked in the page layout assignment).

Any ideas as to what may be the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if user have this permission assigned in profile or permission set
[image]